# Set image as background

Tags: javascript, html, image, background

I want to make a site where there are some images, when I click on an image I want it to be the background image of the site, any suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

Something along the lines of:

```
<img src="myimage.jpg" onClick="document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+this.src+')';;" />
```

Comment: +1 I was about to type up a vanilla Javascript solution in my answer but there's no point really.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily as per below:

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $("#imageId").click(function() {
        var myImage = $("img", this).attr("src");
        $("body").css("background", "url('" + myImage + "')");
    });
});
```

Comment: As Kolink noted, this question is not tagged jQuery.

Comment: True, but seems a little harsh to downvote it anyway. Nowadays it's difficult to disassociate javascript from jQuery...

Answer (score 0):

if you know how to use JQuery, this should be easy:

```
$('#divTagId').click(function()
{
  $("html").css("background-image", "url(/myimage.jpg)");  
});
```